# Installing tensorflow in Windows Anaconda 4.1.1 w Python 2.7

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, anaconda

I have followed the instructions in

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/get_started/os_setup.html#anaconda-installation

activate tensorflow changes the environment as in the instructions

but

conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow

gives me
Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org
Fetching package metadata .........
Solving package specifications: .
Error: Package missing in current win-32 channels:
  - tensorflow

Is there no way to install tensorflow in Windows?

Answer (score 2):

We just announced support for TensorFlow on Windows with the 0.12 release candidate. However, due to the vagaries of [compiler versions on Windows](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers), we only support Python 3.5 (see below for a fuller explanation).

At present there is no conda package for TensorFlow on Windows, but there is a pre-built [PIP package in PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tensorflow). If you install the 64-bit version of Python 3.5, either from Python.org or Anaconda, you can install TensorFlow with the following command (for the CPU-only version):

```
C:\> pip install tensorflow
```

If you have a GPU that supports CUDA 8.0, you can use the following command to install the GPU-accelerated version:

```
C:\> pip install tensorflow-gpu
```

---

**Why does TensorFlow only support Python 3.5 on Windows?** Python on Windows [requires](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers) that you compile extensions using the same compiler as the one that was used to build the Python interpreter. The official distributions of Python 2.7 from Python.org and Anaconda were built with MSVC 9.0. We can't build TensorFlow with MSVC 9.0 (2008), because it relies on too many features from C++11, so we need to use MSVC 14.0 (2015). Only Python 3.5 on Windows was compiled with MSVC 14.0, so we are limited to supporting that version only.

Comment: Would make sense to update the tutorial https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/os_setup

Answer (score 0):

> > > Create a conda environment named tensorflow by invoking the following command:
> > >       C:>conda create -n tensorflow

Activate the conda environment by issuing the following command:
C:> activate tensorflow (tensorflow)C:> # Your prompt should change

Issue the appropriate command to install TensorFlow inside your conda environment. To install the CPU-only version of TensorFlow, enter the following command:

( To get 32- and 64-bit Windows binaries of many scientific open-source extension packages for the official CPython distribution of the Python programming language..... copy link https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)

(tensorflow)C:> pip install — ignore-installed — upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl

1) To install the GPU version of TensorFlow, enter the following command (on a single line):

(tensorflow)C:> pip install — ignore-installed — upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.0.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl

> > > If you are using anaconda distribution and getting the above error, you can do the following to use python 3.5 on the new environnement “tensorflow”:

conda create --name tensorflow python=3.5
activate tensorflow
conda install jupyter
conda install scipy
pip install tensorflow
 or
pip install tensorflow-gpu